# Cant show list for first run time

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, moya, yelp-fusion-api

I am trying to build an app to show a list of things to eat around the user, but I noticed that the first time the app is launched, the list doesn't show up because the user could only tap allow location after the didfinishlaunchingwithoptions function in the AppDelegate finished. My app uses SwiftUI, yelp API, and moya. I tried a lot of things that didnt work. Can anyone help me with this? here is my code:

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Moya
import Alamofire
import AlamofireImage
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {


var theViewModels = [RestrauntListViewModel]()


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.



    let dataSource = DataSource()
    loadBusinesses()
    print("this is the view models in appDelegate: \(theViewModels)")


    return true
}
    func loadBusinesses () {

           let contentView = ContentView()
           let service = MoyaProvider<YelpService.BusinessProvider>()
           let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
           let locationServices = LocationService()
           let lat = locationServices.setup(latOrLong: "lat")
           let long = locationServices.setup(latOrLong: "long")
           locationServices.lat = lat
           locationServices.long = long
           let restrauntView = RestrauntView()
        let appDelegate = AppDelegate()

           if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {


            switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
                   case .notDetermined, .restricted, .denied:
                       print("No access")
                   contentView.tapToDecideText = "Please allow us to use your location in settings so that we can show you restraunts near by. Once you have let us use your location please restart the application."
                   case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
                       print("Access")

                                  service.request(.search(lat: lat, long: long)) { (result) in
                                       switch result{
                                       case.success(let response):
                                           let root = try? jsonDecoder.decode(Root.self, from: response.data)
                                           let viewModels = root?.businesses.compactMap(RestrauntListViewModel.init)
                                           let dataSource = DataSource()
                                           dataSource.arrayOfImages.removeAll()



                                           for image in viewModels! {

                                                       Alamofire.request(image.imageURL).responseImage { response in
                                                           if let image = response.result.value {
                                                               print("image downloadedline 59 appdelegate")
                                                               dataSource.arrayOfImages.append(image)
                                                               print(dataSource.arrayOfImages)
                                                           } else {
                                                               print("ERROR: image does not = response.result.value")
                                                           }
                                                       }
                                                   }

                                           self.theViewModels = (root?.businesses.compactMap(RestrauntListViewModel.init))!


                                           print(" restrauntView.theViewModels is here \(restrauntView.theViewModels)")

                                           print("the constant theViewModels in the appdelegate has \(appDelegate.theViewModels.count) values")

                                       case .failure(let error):
                                           print("Error: \(error)")
                                       }
                   }

                   @unknown default:
                   break
               }



               } else {
                   print("Location services are not enabled")
           }


       }




// MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
    // Called when a new scene session is being created.
    // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
    return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
    // Called when the user discards a scene session.
    // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
    // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
}

// MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    /*
     The persistent container for the application. This implementation
     creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
     application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
     error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    */
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Actrual_Food_Circle")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

            /*
             Typical reasons for an error here include:
             * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
             * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
             * The device is out of space.
             * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
             Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
             */
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}

}
```

**RestrauntView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

struct RestrauntView: View {

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
@State var dataSource = DataSource()
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
var theViewModels = [RestrauntListViewModel]()
lazy var viewModelsCountedUnder1 = self.theViewModels.count - 1



var body: some View {


    List(appDelegate!.theViewModels) { viewModel in
        ListCellView(viewModel: viewModel)
    }


}

init() {
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    print(self.locationManager.location?.coordinate ?? 11111111);
}
}

struct RestrauntView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    RestrauntView()
}
}
```

PS: my listCellView just puts together a small cell view so I thought to save some space I wouldn't put that on here. Thank you :)

Comment: OMG man Moya, Alamofire, AlamofireImage, SwiftUI.... You can take just UIKitPlus + CodyFire and your life became 100x time easier and more beautiful.

Comment: do you have any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: I can help you to build awesome app using UIKitPlus + CodyFire